# How exactly do you calculate matrix $f(A)$ when $A$ is a matrix, $f$ a polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let's say $f \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ and $A \in \mathbb{Q}^{2 \times 2}$.
Now let  $f$  be $f = X^3+2X^2+3X+4$ and $A$ be $A = \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & -1 \\
2 & 3 
\end{pmatrix}$
 how do we calculate the matrix $f(A)$?

I know from the solution, that the $(2,2)$ entry of $f(A)$ is $40$. However, I don't see how we'
d calculate that. I've tried reversing the solution but I did not come far.

Comment: What is $A^2$?  What is $A^3$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since$$3A=\begin{bmatrix}3 & -3 \\ 6 & 9\end{bmatrix},$$since$$2A^2=\begin{bmatrix}-2 & -8 \\ 16 & 14\end{bmatrix},$$and since$$A^3=\begin{bmatrix}-9 & -11 \\ 22 & 13\end{bmatrix},$$we have$$A^3+2A^2+3A+4\operatorname{Id}=\begin{bmatrix}-4 & -22 \\ 44 & 40\end{bmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 7):

The simple approach is to follow the given calculation.  Given $A = \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & -1 \\
2 & 3 
\end{pmatrix}$ we have $$A^2 = \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & -1 \\
2 & 3 
\end{pmatrix}^2=\begin{pmatrix} 
-1 & -4 \\
9 & 7 
\end{pmatrix}$$
One more matrix multiply gets you $A^3$, then you multiply by the scalars and add to get $f(A)$.  For higher powers you can often express $A=P^{-1}DP$ with $D$ diagonal to make the calculations easier because then $A^n=P^{-1}D^nP$ and diagonal matrices are easy to raise to a power.

Comment: If you are going to diagonalise $A$, chances are you are going to find an annihilating polynomial (like the characteristic one) along the way, any then you might as well reduce $f$ modulo that annihilating polynomial to reduce the degree.

Answer (score 6):

If $f(x)=x^3+2x^2+3x+4,$ then $f(A)=A^3+2A^2+3A+4I.$ Can you compute this?